# Why do we use the Earth inertial frame when solving problems involving non-inertial reference frames?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I was solving a question in my textbook that was under the heading "Solving Problems Related to Objects in a Non-inertial Frame of Reference"

The problem reads

> "A teacher suspends a small cork ball from the ceiling of a bus. When the bus accelerates at a constant rate forward, the string suspending the ball makes an angle of $10^{o}$ with the vertical. Calculate the magnitude of the acceleration of the bus."

The first few words of the solution read

> "Analysis: Look at the situation from an Earth (inertial) frame of reference."

Why do we use the Earth inertial frame when solving problems involving non-inertial reference frames? On top of that in the solution, they also equate $F_T\sin(\theta) = ma$ which how can we do if we are in a non-inertial reference frame?

Answer (score 7):

> Why do we use the earth inertial frame when solving problems involving non-inertial reference frames?

Because we can.

This is the meaning of the general principle of relativity. You can use any reference frame that you want. The explanations may differ, but all reference frames will agree on the outcome of any measurement.

A reference frame is not a box that something is in or out of. A reference frame is a choice of coordinates. It is part of the analysis, not part of the physical scenario. So you have the freedom to choose the reference frame that is most convenient for the analysis. There is no right or wrong choice. If you do the math correctly then you are guaranteed to get a valid answer.

> they also equate $F_T\sin(\theta) = ma$  which how can we do if we are in a non-inertial reference frame?

As you said earlier, they are using an inertial frame for the analysis. So Newton’s 2nd law holds.

Comment: That's clearly not what the OP was asking. Newton's laws hold within the space and time constraints of a desk experiment simply because the acceleration on the Earth's surface is small enough that its effects disappear in the measurement errors. You need continental space -- e.g. for the Coriolis force affecting air currents -- or minutes of observation -- e.g. for Foucault's pendulum -- to observe its effects. That this is not about general relativity is clear from the wording "from an Earth **(inertial)** frame of reference".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I didn't speak of general relativity but the general _principle_ of relativity. Basically, that is that the laws of physics do not depend on the coordinate system you use. This principle applies to Newtonian physics also

Comment: In Newtonian physics, accelerated systems cannot serve as reference.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica they certainly can. Maybe try calculating the Lagrange points without using non-inertial coordinates. Or using a Lagrangian with inertial vs non-inertial coordinates. Newton's laws are traditionally expressed in terms of inertial frames, but that doesn't mean that Newtonian physics is limited to such frames.

Comment: Arguably, the Lagrangian approach is different from the Newtonian.